# Block postion fixed below accurate width of browser

Tags: jquery, css

I have script as below:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
if ($(window).width() >= 992){  

    var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
var $this = this,
    $window = $(windw);

$window.scroll(function(e){
    if ($window.scrollTop() > pos){
        $this.css({
            position: 'static',
            top: pos,
            marginTop: 100


        });
    }
    else {
        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 100
        });
    }

});
};


 $('#bgForm').followTo(1550);    



}   
});
```

I'd like to block position fixed when the size of browser is below 992px. How can I do this using my script?
I try with this code, but then the element stop on position. 
Thank you!

Comment: I've update my code. Please check

Comment: can you write it? Becasue I don't exactly know what you mean.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using javascript for this?

Comment: Is it solution not to use javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @designedbyscott stated, I think a media query is the simplest solution, but since you've asked about your JS script, here is a simplified version which just creates a function to check the window width and apply your position change accordingly. It is called on load, resize, and scroll, though you can decide what is best for you. Change 'your-element' to the element you'd like to target.

```
function positionFix() {
  element = $('.your-element');
  width = $(window).width();
  scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (width >= 992 || scroll > 1550) {
    element.css('position','static');
    element.css('margin-top','100px');
  } else {
    element.css('position','fixed');
    element.css('top','100');  
    element.css('margin-top','0');  
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", positionFix);
window.addEventListener("resize", positionFix);
window.addEventListener("scroll", positionFix);
```

Comment: but in my code this element stops on accurate position, now scroll with no stop to the end of page.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "stops on accurate position"? Or post a fiddle

Comment: Look at my code, there is $('#bgForm').followTo(1550); this is form, which has fixed position and when you scroll down form goes with you. But I want to stop this in accurate place - 1550 px. How can I include this requirement in your code?

Comment: You are genius! Thank you!!

Comment: @Steve far from it, but I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see why you would be using Javascript when a simple CSS media query would suffice. Unless there's more to your question you haven't stated?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    // Rules placed here will only apply when the 
    // browser window is smaller than 992px
}
```